# Handling multiple click events on button in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android. I am developing one app. In my app i have DashBoard Activity having multiple button each button have some asyn tasks. When i click multiple times on a button it is performing multiple asyntasks which leads problems to me.. Please help me out from this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Multiple tasks? It is normal I guess.. the button will perform its task, the number of times you click on it. Why don't you use a boolean variable to check that the action has been already performed. Something like this

`

```
if (true)
   {  
    your task 
   }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with setting flag. You should also do this..

```
void startBackgroundTask()
    {
        if (backgroundTask == null || backgroundTask.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
        {
            backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
            Object[] params =
            { "", object };
            backgroundTask.execute(params);
        } else
            Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.task_is_running), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in each buttons' onClickListener that checks if the asyncTask is already being executed..